# Round not rounding to decimal precision

Tags: python, rounding

I've written a temperature converter as a personal project, to test myself. It seems to work well, except that it's not rounding the returned temperature to two decimal places. I'm using round(), but it's not working as expected. Here's my code:

```
scale_in = ""
scale_out = ""
temp = 0.0
converted_temp = 0.00

def toKelvin():
    global temp
    global scale_in
    global scale_out
    global converted_temp
    scale_out = "Kelvin"
    if(scale_in == "c"):
        # Convert from Celsius to Kelvin
        converted_temp = float(temp) + 273.15
    elif(scale_in == "f"):
        # Convert from Fahrenheit to Kelvin
        converted_temp = ((float(temp) - 32.0) / 1.799) + 273.15

    return converted_temp

def toCelsius():
    global temp
    global scale_in
    global scale_out
    global converted_temp
    scale_out = "Celsius"
    if(scale_in == "f"):
        # Converts Fahrenheit to Celsius
        converted_temp = ((float(temp) - 32) * 5) / 9
    elif(scale_in == "k"):
        # Convert Kelvin to Celsius
        converted_temp = float(temp) - 273.15

    return converted_temp

def toFahrenheit():
    global temp
    global scale_in
    global scale_out
    global converted_temp
    scale_out = "Fahrenheit"
    if(scale_in == "c"):
        # Converts Celsius Fahrenheit
        converted_temp = ((float(temp) * 1.8) + 32)
    elif(scale_in) == "k":
        # Kelvin to Fahrenheit ()
        converted_temp = (float(temp) * 1.8) - 459.67

    return converted_temp

def getTemp():
    global temp
    # Get the current temperature from the user
    while(temp == 0.0):
        temp = input("What is the current temperature? ")
        # Check that we've been given a valid number
        try:
            float(temp)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid entry. Please enter a number.")
            temp = 0.0
            
    return temp

def get_scale_in():
    scale = input('Converting from K, C or F?')
    return scale 

def get_scale_out():
    scale = input("Converting to K, C or F?")
    return scale

def convert():
    global scale_in
    global scale_out
    global temp
    # Get the scale used by the user -- Kelvin, Celsius or Fahrenheit
    scale_in = get_scale_in()
    scale_out = get_scale_out()
    
    if(scale_out.lower() == "f"):
        converted_temp = round(float(toFahrenheit()), 2)
    elif(scale_out.lower() == "c"):
        converted_temp = round(float(toCelsius()), 2)
    elif(scale_out.lower() == "k"):
        converted_temp = round(float(toKelvin()), 2)
    else:
        print("Invalid input.")


temp = getTemp()
convert()

# Print the result
print(f"The temperature is {converted_temp} {scale_out}.")
```

I've tried adding float() to the temp variable in the three top functions (toKelvin, toCelsius, toFahrenheit), but that hasn't solved the problem. Here's one example of the output:

```
What is the current temperature? 42
Converting from K, C or F?f
Converting to K, C or F?c
The temperature is 5.555555555555555 Celsius.
```

How can I limit the output to two decimal places, and, if possible, why is this happening?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (emphasis on *minimal*) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Get rid of the globals.  Pass `temp` and `scale_in` as arguments and return the result.

Comment: Also, don't use so many global variables. You probably didn't even notice that `convert` sets a *local* variable `converted_temp`, rather than updating the global variable, because the various `to...` functions are also updating the global `converted_temp`.

Comment: As a result, you are never rounding the value actually assigned to the global `converted_temp`.

Comment: you never round the value being referred to by the global variable. Basically, you shouldn't be using mutable global state - in my entire career writing Python code professionally, I have never used the `global` statement once.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points